# Get previous and next document by date in Elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch index contains documents each having a date field. The documents can be sorted by date.

Supposed I have a specific document ID and its date, what is the best way to get the previous and next document inside the index by date?

I had a look at the fuzzy query with dates but it does not solve the problem directly. It would return the most similar documents but not necessarily the previous and next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it, but it takes two requests. To test I defined a simple index and added a few docs:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "doc_date": {
               "type": "date",
               "format": "YYYY-MM-dd"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-21"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-22"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-23"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-24"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-25"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"doc_date":"2015-5-26"}
```

Now I can choose a date, say `"2015-5-23"`, and get the next doc like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 1,
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "doc_date": {
                  "gt": "2015-5-23"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "doc_date": {
            "order": "asc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "doc_date": "2015-5-24"
            },
            "sort": [
               1432425600000
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and the previous one like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 1,
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "doc_date": {
                  "lt": "2015-5-23"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "doc_date": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "doc_date": "2015-5-22"
            },
            "sort": [
               1432252800000
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Not sure off-hand how to do it in a single request. I'll give it some thought.

Here is the code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/ffeda4baeafac27dcc11e2010594015c98e6d40f

Comment: OK, thanks. That would be the easiest way. I hoped to get an elegant solution with only one query...